# Good sites/blogs for FPGA development projects

Tags: embedded, vhdl, fpga, firmware

I'm looking for interesting online resources on FPGA development - sites, blogs, that sort of thing. What I'm after is examples of fun (and hopefully not too expensive) projects that one can try out and learn from.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

have you tried [fpga4fun.com](http://www.fpga4fun.com/) or [fpga-forum.com](http://www.fpga-forum.com/wbb/)?

Also [mikrocontroller.net](http://www.mikrocontroller.net/) (altough in german) [has a linklist](http://www.mikrocontroller.net/articles/Linksammlung#Programmierbare_Logik_.28CPLD.2FFPGA.2FGAL.29).

Answer (score 4):

[John Kent's site](http://members.optushome.com.au/jekent/FPGA.htm) is a good starting point.

Answer (score 2):

Try opencores.org - it hosts open source projects.

Comment: The average project quality on opencores is not very good. It is also hard to access the files there as they require you to sign up to actually download the files.

Answer (score 1):

Great site with interesting projects and articles

http://www.fpga4fun.com/

Answer (score 1):

I've compiled a list of FPGA Online Resources. Check link

[fpga-blog.tumblr.com/links](http://fpga-blog.tumblr.com/links/)